# Split a string at nth occurrence of a regex in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, arrays, string, split

I know `split` can get a second parameter as a limit, but it is not what I'm looking for. And I know it can be done by splitting and joining again with a solid string delimiter.

The problem is the delimiter is a regular expression and I don't know the exact length of the pattern that matches.

Consider this string:

```
this is a title
--------------------------
rest is body! even if there are some dashes!
--------
---------------------
it should not be counted as a separated part!
```

By using this:

```
str.split(/---*\n/);
```

I will get:

```
[
  'this is a title',
  'rest is body! even if there are some dashes.!',
  '',
  'it should not be counted as a separated part!'
]
```

And this is what I wanted to be: (if I want to split by **the first occurrence**)

```
[
  'this is a title',
  'rest is body! even if there are some dashes.!\n--------\n---------------------\nit should not be counted as a separated part!'
]
```

This solution is what I currently have, but it's just for the first occurrence.

```
function split(str, regex) {
    var match = str.match(regex);
    return [str.substr(0, match.index), str.substr(match.index+match[0].length)];
}
```

Any ideas on how to generalize the solution for any number *n* to split the string on the n<sup>th</sup> occurrence of regex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var str= "this-----that---these------those";
var N= 2;
var regex= new RegExp( "^((?:[\\s\\S]*?---*){"+(N-1)+"}[\\s\\S]*?)---*([\\s\\S]*)$" );
var result= regex.exec(str).slice(1,3);
console.log(result);
```

Output:

```
["this-----that", "these------those"]
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/86AyK/1/)
**Option with the function:**

```
var generateRegExp= function (N) {
    return new RegExp( "^((?:[\\s\\S]*?---*){"+(N-1)+"}[\\s\\S]*?)---*([\\s\\S]*)$" );
};

var getSlice= function(str, regexGenerator, N) {
    return regexGenerator(N).exec(str).slice(1,3);
};

var str= "this-----that---these------those";
var N= 2;
var result= getSlice(str, generateRegExp, N);
console.log(result);
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/86AyK/2/)

**Option with the function 2:**

```
var getSlice= function(str, regex, N) {
    var re= new RegExp( "^((?:[\\s\\S]*?"+regex+"){"+(N-1)+"}[\\s\\S]*?)"+regex+"([\\s\\S]*)$" );
    return re.exec(str).slice(1,3);
};

var str= "this-----that---these------those";
var N= 3;
var result= getSlice(str, "---*", N);
console.log(result);
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/86AyK/3/)

Comment: Thanks.

That's better than my solution, but I'm looking for a solution to split a string by nth occurrence of a regex. Your solution splits the string only by the first occurrence.

Comment: Amir, give an example of the source text and the result in the case of Nth occurrence (N=2 or more).

Comment: Imagine this string: 'this-----that---these------those'. if N=2 (1-based), the result should be: ['this-----that', 'these------those']

Comment: Great! :)

Is it possible to do that with any regular expressions? Say we want to write a function that gets the string, regular expression and N, then returns the result array!

Comment: By having a function I meant a function that generate the desired regex itself, and transparent the behavior from the one who use the function. `split('this-----that---these------those', /---*/, 2)` for example. So we can use it with any regex this way! Anyway, thank you for your response! It is really appreciated :)